# validate created filename against a specified pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find out if my created files have file names that are matching the pattern.

For example: My created file's file name will be in format 17-06-27_11-02-34_9530114

> where the First part 17-06-27 : YY-MM-DD  second part
>   11-02-34:Hour:Minutes:Seconds  Third part 9530114: some id

how can I write a regular expression in JavaScript to check the pattern as well as check if the first two parts that is the date and time are matching the date and time of the birth of the file.

Answer (score 0):

[0-9][1-9]-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])*(0[0-9]|1[0-2])-([0-5][0-9])-([0-5][0-9])*\d{7}

For testing purposes use this [link](https://regex101.com/r/T8IUgj/1)

Answer (score 0):

This regex will match the example you gave: `/^((\d\d-){2}\d\d_){2}\d{7}$/`

To test it in your browser's console, try this:

```js
/^((\d\d-){2}\d\d_){2}\d{7}$/.test('17-06-27_11-02-34_9530114')
```